# Finding location where Matlab warning was triggered

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I have a large codebase in Matlab (2021a Update 5, running on Mac) which triggers the warning:

`Warning: Integer operands are required for colon operator when used as index.`

But there is no information about where this warning is triggered. How can I find out what file and line-number it came from? So I can adress the problem.

Comment: Try running `warning on backtrace` before running your script

Comment: You can also do `dbstop if warning`, which will drop you into the debugger at the point where the warning happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) provided an excellent solution in a comment, so I thought I might repeat it and flag the question as answered.*

To break the execution at the first line that's triggering a warning, run the following command in the Command Window beforehand.

`dbstop if warning`

From what I can tell, the following command resets this option.

`dbclear all`